# pass named argument to program in shell

Tags: bash, quotes

I want to pass some additional named arguments to a programe in shell script. Say I have following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="/root/serv er/conf/config.yml"
EXEARG="-configFile \"$FILE\""
"/root/serv er/bin/server" $EXEARG
```

I put EXEARG on separate line because I may change it in another process(for example jenkins build). But `bash -x myscript` gives me this:

```
+ FILE='/root/serv er/conf/config.yml'
+ EXEARG='-configFile "/root/serv er/conf/config.yml"'
+ '/root/serv er/bin/server' -configFile '"/root/serv' 'er/conf/config.yml"'
```

I'm expecting:
`'/root/serv er/bin/server' -configFile "/root/serv er/conf/config.yml"`
How should I do that?

Comment: Paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: WOW! Didn't know this excellent tool before. Problem solved. Thanks @Cyrus

Comment: BTW, this is also the topic of [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 0):

Using the tool recommended by @Cyrus, I solved it by [SC2089](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2089)